# How to pause JavaScript after page done loading?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, onload

I am loading an HTML page in my browser from a web site. *As far as I understand, the browser loads the page first, then starts executing the JavaScript code on it.*

***Question:*** How can I pause the JavaScript execution in Google Chrome as soon as the page is done loading, and then start it after, manually?

What I am trying to achieve is to load the page in a browser (any browser, but preferably Google Chrome), but edit the javascript code before it starts executing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'edit' the Javascript?

Comment: @dave I mean that I want to edit the javascript code on the page, before it starts executing

Comment: Are you talking about an evil post-load-javascript-manipulation or a basic timeout? Also, how would you "edit the javascript code" if, to check if the dom has been loaded, you probably are already using javascript..?

Comment: Are you trying to debug a page? Chrome allows you to set breakpoints and pause execution in the Developer Tools.

Comment: Your assumption isn't always true, but you could use the HTML body elements `onload` handler, to execute a script once the page loads.  Also, Chrome has built-in developer tools to set breakpoints and debug the javascript.

Comment: place a breakpoint in the first line of the first js file declared in the html. You can find all js files under sources tab in the dev console in chrome. cmd + option + i to bring it up.

Comment: @briosheje I am not sure what that is. All I am basically trying to do is to make an HTML page run my own javascript code, instead of it's original. I just want to edit the code before it starts executing.

Comment: @Victor2748: if you want to run your own javascript code in a foreign html page then no, you cannot "directly" do that, you might be able to accomplish some by using some Browser Extensions, but will be working for YOU only, not for someone else. Is the page loaded your (or in your domain) or is that a foreign page?

Comment: I need to completely replace an attached .js file.
`The page has: <script src="path/to/file.js"></script>`
I need to execute my own .js file instead of that one. is there a way to replace it before it starts executing?

Comment: Answer to the question: are you the owner of the page? What you are trying to do seems to apparently be injecting your own code inside a website. This can be done without having any "evil" intention, but the result will only be available for you, because the server is responding you with an HTML document that contains some JS. As far as you know what you want to do, you may be able to inject your own code, but can you please explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @briosheje No, I am not the owner of the page, otherwise I could just edit the page itself on the host.

Comment: Then be aware that you will be the only one who will see the result. Apart from that, a good solution is using the Chrome comfortable developer debugger. Another solution is using a third-party extention. For such task, you might want to check https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=it , which allows you to write and execute your own javascript code after the page has been loaded. You maybe won't be able to entirely replace a script, but you will be able to execute your after it has been loaded.

Comment: @briosheje I am trying to inject my javascript code on someone's page, but only in my own browser, so that will not affect anyone else. I am not doing it for an "evil" purpose.

Comment: @Victor2748: I know, that's why you should try tampermonkey :)

Comment: @briosheje Thank you. That is what I needed <3. You can post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @Victor2748: no need to, I'm already happy enough if I've helped you ;). Remember to check the headers of your userscripts, that's where you can tell to the browser where and when to execute your own script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Debugging Javascript in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). You can set breakpoints at the beginning of any JS file and then continue from there.

> ## **Debugging with breakpoints**
>
> A breakpoint is an intentional stopping or
> pausing place in a script. Use breakpoints in DevTools to debug
> JavaScript code, DOM updates, and network calls.
>
> Click the line gutter to set a breakpoint for that line of code. A
> blue tag will indicate if a breakpoint has been set

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Google Chrome you can achieve this with the developer tools (and in most other popular browsers). Open them with F12 and set a breakpoint in your script under the "Sources" tab.

You can then edit and save (Ctrl-S) your script and press F8 to continue execution with the new code.